# Weka API: Installing package using package manager

Tags: weka, libsvm

I am trying to use libsvm via Weka API. I have added weka-dev-3.7.6.jar and libsvm.jar to my eclipse build path. The following is the code to load the libsvm library

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(true);
        AbstractClassifier classifier = ( AbstractClassifier ) Class.forName(
                "weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM" ).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println("error 1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println("error 2");

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.err.println("error 3");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I got the following error

```
Refreshing GOE props...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: java_cup/runtime/SymbolFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

I added java-cup-11b-runtime.jar on the build path. However, the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run your application with a JVM that does not support Java 8.

Install a Java 8 compatible JRE (or JDK if you need it for development) and use the included JVM to run your application.

Here are the major.minor version numbers mapped to Java versions:

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) for a Wikipedia reference.